# Fast Deserialization from JSON

Tags: c#, json

Currently in my code I retrieve a string value and then deserialize it to a Dictionary using JsonConvert.  This works perfectly fine, but I was curious as to if there was a faster way for me to do this in order to increase performance.

I tried deserializing directly from a stream rather than going to string first, but my Dictionary kept being returned as "null".  I know deserializing from a stream is possible, as I have done it in other projects

```
// Using JsonConvert (works but would like to be faster)
Dictionary<int, MyClass> myDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, MyClass>>(myString);

// Using Streams directly (Dictionary is returned as null even though I have confirmed the stream is not empty)
// In my actual code this is within a function that returns a Dictionary and takes the stream as a parameter
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myStream))
using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    return serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, MyClass>>(jsonTextReader);
}
```

As I said before, using JsonConvert gets me the correct result, but I was hoping somebody could either help me with the stream one, or provide another idea for deserialization that could be faster. Thanks!

Comment: JsonConvert is built for performance. It's unlikely that you can get much faster than that prior to .net core 3. In .net core 3 (currently in preview7) the .net team implements a new and faster serializer to get rid of old json.net dependencies. You can read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/).

Comment: As far as I know ``JsonConvert`` with defined class type is the fastest approach for now.

Comment: *I tried deserializing directly from a stream rather than going to string first, but my Dictionary kept being returned as "null"* - can you share a [mcve]?  Possibly you just forgot to rewind the stream if you had already read `myString` from it.  Also, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm

Comment: Problem of famost general parsers is they are too complex and use too much memory per object... You can get few times better speed using some lighter alternative - made one in C# translating Gason from C++ https://github.com/eltomjan/gason